# Extract Last Part of URL using PHP

Tags: php, url

How I can extract the last part of a URL using PHP.

Here is sample URL

> `http://www.example.com/123`

I want following output

> 123

How can I do this in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this piece of code is work for me

```
 $id = substr($url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1);
```

`strrpos` gets the position of the last occurrence of the slash; `substr` returns everything after that position.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to solve this.

1. Use `parse_url` and get the path
2. Find the position of the `/` character and then extract the string based on that
3. Use a regular expression (`/\d+$/`)
4. Trim the numbers off the end (`rtrim($url, '0123456789')`), compare the lengths and, if not the same, calculate the difference and then extract the number.
5. Using a simple loop you can iterate over the string backwards, checking if the characters are numbers. If they are then prepend them to a string, otherwise stop the loop.

I could probably find other ways to do it but I think this should do just fine. If you cannot figure it out then it is because of a lack of imagination.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/123";
echo str_replace('/','', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to achieve what you want:

```
<?php
    $uri = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    $uri = $uri[0];
    $part_uri = explode( "/", $uri);
    print_r( $uri );
    print_r( $part_uri );
?>
```

$part_uri will become an array of the current website path.
For example will http://adomain.com/manual/test result in:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => manual [2] => test )
```

So to get your "123" you would use $part_uri[1]

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
end(explode('/', $url))
```

Answer (score 0):

try `substr()`

```
echo substr('http://www.example.com/123', -3);
```

or `parse_url()`

```
$p =parse_url('http://www.example.com/123');
echo str_replace('/', '', $p['path']);
```